# Is there any possibility of using boto3 to get On Demand, Reserved and Spot Instance Requests Limits

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto3

For a Python script I'm working on, I have managed to calculate the total  Reserved, On Demand, and Spot instance request. What I'm after is a way to get the **max limit** for each instance type e.g.

What the expected output should look like:-

```
Instance Type: t2.medium, current:5, max:20
Instance Type: t2.large, current:20, max:50'
...
```

I have researched and not found a way of doing this, (I'm sure there might be a way to do it with TrustedAdvisor, but my company doesn't have the right support package meaning we have no access to the TrustedAdvisor api)

Since they have added it in AWS console (EC2 Limits section) it should allow us to call for it using the api and boto3

Comment: Trusted adviser is the only AFAIK. Check out https://github.com/jantman/awslimitchecker

Comment: I knew that, I was asking for an alternative way.
Why should I use trustedadvisor when it's not required in the aws console. You can get those limits in the ec2 service alone, so why not add support to make it through the api calls. **P.S still looking for a solution. (Need it as I'm making my own limitchecker script which is aimed at those with no access to make trusted advisor api calls. Once complete, I'll add to github for others to use as an alternative to jantmans awslimitchecker.)**

Comment: @YordanIbishev were you able to complete the above?